# Create a dictionary from a csv file where a specific column is the key and the rows are the values in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file formatted as below:

```
jersey number,   position,   name,   birth_date,    birth_city,   years_in_nba,   team
23           ,     SF    ,   Lebron,  12/30/84 ,     Akron    ,      19      ,   Lakers
30           ,     PG    ,   Curry,   03/14/88 ,     Akron    ,      13      ,   Warriors
34           ,     PF    ,   Giannis, 08/26/89 ,     Athens    ,      8      ,   Bucks
```

My goal is to be able to group the rows by position where the key is the different positions and and the values are a list of player info having in common the same position like below:

```
{
"SF": [{..player1..}, {..player2..}],
"PF": [{..player1..}, {..player2..}],
"SG": [{..player1..}, {..player2..}],
"PG": [{..player1..}, {..player2..}],
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
positions = {}
def players_position():
with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
    dict_reader = DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=",")
    for row in dict_reader:
        positions[row["position"]] = row
return positions

print(players_position())
```

with the code as it is, the current value will always override the previous one. I don't want that. I want to have a list where we can keep appending player info like displayed above.

Comment: Does the CSV file really have whitespace around all the commas?

Comment: Make `positions` a `defaultdict(list)` and use `positions[row["position"]].append(row)`

Comment: Please fix your code. I don't think the indentation you show here is what you actually have in the code. Also, there are some syntax errors.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Those syntax errors are due to the Stacks editor escaping characters unnecessarily.

Comment: I was having some formatting issue with the csv file. it does not have whitespace around commas. It looks more like this.

jersey_number,position,name,birth_date,birth_city,college,years_in_nba,team
23,SF,LeBron James,12/30/84,"Akron,  Ohio",None,19,Los Angeles Lakers
30,PG,Stephen Curry,3/14/88,"Akron,  Ohio",Davidson,13,Golden State Warriors
7,PF,Kevin Durant,9/29/88,"Washington D.C., Texas",Texas,15,Brooklyn Nets
13,SG,James Harden,8/26/89,"Los Angeles,  California",Arizona State,12,Brooklyn Nets
34,PF,Giannis Antetokounmpo,12/6/94,"Athens,  Greece",None,8,Milwaukee Bucks

Comment: @Barmar with the append you suggested I have the error below:

 positions[row["position"]].append(row)
 KeyError: 'SF'

Comment: That shouldn't happen. `collections.defaultdict()` will automatically create the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I originally tried basing this off what you had, but because the data when split in the CSV raw data ends up with a bunch of whitespace padding, I did a little extra work to clean up the keys/values.

```
import csv

CSV = """
# jersey number,   position,   name,   birth_date,    birth_city,   years_in_nba,   team
# 23           ,     SF    ,   Lebron,  12/30/84 ,     Akron    ,      19      ,   Lakers
# 30           ,     PG    ,   Curry,   03/14/88 ,     Akron    ,      13      ,   Warriors
# 34           ,     PF    ,   Giannis, 08/26/89 ,     Athens    ,      8      ,   Bucks
"""


def main():
    players = [player for player in csv.DictReader(CSV.splitlines())]
    # gives me:

    """
    {None: ['# jersey number', '   position', '   name', '   birth_date', '    birth_city', '   years_in_nba', '   team']}
    {None: ['# 23           ', '     SF    ', '   Lebron', '  12/30/84 ', '     Akron    ', '      19      ', '   Lakers']}
    {None: ['# 30           ', '     PG    ', '   Curry', '   03/14/88 ', '     Akron    ', '      13      ', '   Warriors']}
    {None: ['# 34           ', '     PF    ', '   Giannis', ' 08/26/89 ', '     Athens    ', '      8      ', '   Bucks']}
    """

    # strip the keys because extra whitespace, and because of how DictReader makes arrays, we have to do this:
    keys = [k.strip() for k in [v for v in players.pop(0).values()][0]]

    # then let's gather the players and strip the values so they don't have unnecessary spaces
    players = [[p.strip() for p in list(p.values())[0]] for p in [v for v in players]]

    # and combine (zip) the keys and values to make a dictionary
    players_list = [dict(zip(keys, p)) for p in players]

    # this gives me:
    """
    {'# jersey number': '# 23', 'position': 'SF', 'name': 'Lebron', 'birth_date': '12/30/84', 'birth_city': 'Akron', 'years_in_nba': '19', 'team': 'Lakers'}
    {'# jersey number': '# 30', 'position': 'PG', 'name': 'Curry', 'birth_date': '03/14/88', 'birth_city': 'Akron', 'years_in_nba': '13', 'team': 'Warriors'}
    {'# jersey number': '# 34', 'position': 'PF', 'name': 'Giannis', 'birth_date': '08/26/89', 'birth_city': 'Athens', 'years_in_nba': '8', 'team': 'Bucks'}
    """

    # last, create a dictionary of lists grouping by position using a list comprehension
    # you could do this in a for loop, but we're writing python, after all...
    players_by_position = {
        position: [
        player for player in players_list if player['position'] == position
      ] for position in set([player['position'] for player in players_list])
    }
    
    return players_by_position

    """
    {
      'SF': [
        {
          '# jersey number': '# 23', 
          'position': 'SF', 
          'name': 'Lebron', 
          'birth_date': '12/30/84', 
          'birth_city': 'Akron', 
          'years_in_nba': '19', 
          'team': 'Lakers'
        }
      ], 
      'PG': [
        {
          '# jersey number': '# 30', 
          'position': 'PG', 
          'name': 'Curry', 
          'birth_date': '03/14/88', 
          'birth_city': 'Akron', 
          'years_in_nba': '13', 
          'team': 'Warriors'
        }
      ], 
      'PF': [
        {
          '# jersey number': '# 34', 
          'position': 'PF', 
          'name': 'Giannis', 
          'birth_date': '08/26/89', 
          'birth_city': 'Athens', 
          'years_in_nba': '8', 
          'team': 'Bucks'
        }
      ]
    }
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```